# How to implement CordovaInterface so that I can use camera in the webview?

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview, android-camera

I am new to Android.

I embedded Cordova `WebView` on my Android app by following the [tutorial](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20Android).

I already successfully load a webpage from my server by using `CordovaWebView`.

Let's say that I have a button on that webPage called "Capture Photo", what should I do to call the local API so that I can use the camera?

The tutorial suggest that I need to implement the `CordovaInterface` to use camera in the way as follow.

```
@Override
public void setActivityResultCallback(CordovaPlugin plugin) {
    this.activityResultCallback = plugin;        
}
```

I don't know what exactly is **activityResultCallback**. Is there another tutorial to show me how to implement this interface?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since nobody answer my question.

I find a [tutorial](http://www.infil00p.org/advanced-tutorial-using-cordovawebview-on-android/) that can solve this problem.

Update:
Given that the link is broken, I'll post my own code for implementing the Cordova Interface.

```
// Instance for CordovaInterface
private final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
private boolean mAlternateTitle = false;
private boolean bound;
private boolean volumeupBound;
private boolean volumedownBound;
private CordovaPlugin activityResultCallback;
private Object activityResultKeepRunning;
private Object keepRunning;


public Activity getActivity() {
    return this;
}

@Deprecated
public Context getContext() {
    return this;
}

public ExecutorService getThreadPool() {
    return threadPool;
}


public void setActivityResultCallback(CordovaPlugin plugin) {
    this.activityResultCallback = plugin;

}

public void startActivityForResult(CordovaPlugin command, Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    this.activityResultCallback = command;
    this.activityResultKeepRunning = this.keepRunning;

    // If multitasking turned on, then disable it for activities that return
    // results
    if (command != null) {
        this.keepRunning = false;
    }

    // Start activity
    super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    final CordovaPlugin callback = this.activityResultCallback;
    if (callback != null) {
        // Need to use background thread
        this.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                callback.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Ive been trying to use the geolocation plugin with phonegap 3.0. I get an error "Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool()".
I wasn't getting this error till a few days back. Suddenly started getting it. Am i supposed to implement the CordovaInterface for every plugin i wish to use and how do i do it ?

Comment: Found a link to the tutorial used: http://phonegap.infil00p.org/android/cordova/phonegap/2012/12/04/advanced-tutorial-using-cordovawebview-on-android/

Comment: Updating link: http://infil00p.org/android/cordova/phonegap/2012/12/04/advanced-tutorial-using-cordovawebview-on-android/